# HAProxy - Configure Name and Port Proxies for different backends

Tags: haproxy

Background:  We have a series of interconnected applications SSL and all that we need to test putting a load balancer in front of.  We're looking to publicly expose '443' to the end-users but have HAProxy proxy/redirect to the required internally exposed tcp-listeners.  We're testing this implementation with haproxy and thought it would be a bit easier than either it is or we're making it to be.

- https://example.com/app1 -> backend of 6 different hosts (or the
  internal fqdn (not sure which would be correct)) on 30001
- https://example.com/app2 -> backend of 6 different hosts (or the
  internal fqdn (not sure which would be correct))on 8443
- ...

We've tried a number of different frontend/backend configs but can't seem to make it work as we intend.  If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.  Also we do not want SSL to terminate on the HAproxy which is why we aren't providing certs in the bind statement.

test1:

```
frontend test
    bind *:443
    acl path_spgen path_beg -i /app1
    use_backend be_spgen if path_spgen

backend be_spgen
    server host-01 x.x.x.x:30001
```

test2:

```
frontend test
    bind *:443
    acl path_spgen path_beg -i /app1
   http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
   http-request redirect code 301 location https://example:30001 if path_spgen

backend be_spgen
    server host-01 x.x.x.x:30001
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to route traffic based on HTTP values, but you want the traffic to remain encrypted and unavailable to haproxy. That's your mistake. Terminate SSL on haproxy, so it can decrypt the traffic, read HTTP stuff, like path and then it will have data on which it can route your traffic as you want. You can encrypt traffic to backends after that if you want/need.

Comment: yeah that ended up being the issue -- just my ignorance SSL packet structure and that tcp mode is L4 and http mode is L7.  I wasn't making that connection yesterday.  If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll mark it.  Thanks